# How to get GPS-ONLY positions?

Tags: iphone, gps, wifi, cllocationmanager, cellular-network

The positions from Wi-Fi or Cellular Tower by iPhone CLLocationManager are not accurate enough for tracking routes. I want only the positions from GPS.

For the moment I use `newLocation.horizontalAccuracy` in `didUpdateToLocation` to filter:

```
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 || newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 100) return;
```

because I find that when the location "jump" to an inaccurate position (possibly Cell Tower position), the horizontalAccuracy is 100, so I use 100 to filter it out.

What is the best way of getting GPS-ONLY positions, despite of accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get GPS-only data. It's my understanding that the CLLocation is calculated based on GPS, cell towers as well as any available wireless networks within range.

Comment: This news might be of interest to you: "In April, Apple Ditched Google And Skyhook In Favor Of Its Own Location Databases"  http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/29/apple-location/